# Is it worth to assert that only entry is returned on a foreign key request?

Tags: database, sqlite

I have two tables `A` with its primary key `id` and `B` containing a foreign key column referring to `A` ids.
I was wondering if when I query the `A` entry referenced by the foreign key of a `B` entry, would I need to ensure that the query has returned me one and exactly one result ?
I am quite new in databases world, but I believe the database ensure that the entry referred by a foreign key is unique and never deleted, am I right ?

Comment: What part of the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) is unclear?

Comment: Apart from that ... how can that question be tagged as both mysql and sqlite?

Comment: If the foreign key column is not `NULL`, the entry referred is existing for sure right ? But since this column could be set to `nullable`, a check is necessary, at least to see if this column is not `NULL`, isn't it ?